# Can JSTL var names be set from expressions or do they have to be literal strings?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'm new to JSTL and I want to generalize some functionality that's used multiple times in one tag into a separate tag. My idea is to pass this tag an array of strings. That's no problem. But I also want to name some variables based on those strings so that I can reuse the results of  expressions within the local scope.

Example:

```
<c:set var="hasFirstName" value="false"/>
```

I want to test for "hasFirstName" at various places within the tag. But the names will change depending upon the input. So is there any way to do something like this?

```
<c:forTokens var="formName" items="firstName,middleName,lastName" delims=",">
        <c:set var="has_${formName}" value="false"/>
</c:forTokens>
```

Comment: You could always try it and find out...

Comment: @skaffman: I did try it, but the page is failing for other reasons and I want to make sure this is *not* the reason. As I say, I'm new to JSTL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will work, it will only be stored as `has_firstName`, not as `hasFirstName`.

You *could* substring and uppercase the 1st character with [JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html), but that's clumsy.